Removing a file does not increase available space?
OS is Debian. I am running as root. Output of df -h /:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       99G  97G  0   100% /

lsof shows /var/log/syslog file handle is open, but nothing related to /var/log/syslog.7.gz.
So I removed /var/log/syslog.7.gz to try and free up a few hundred megabytes of disk space.
Output of df -h / again:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       99G  97G  0   100% /

Tried this for a few files in /var/log. First I check to make sure the file handle is not open with lsof, then I try to remove it, immediately check df, avail is still zero. Did this with a bunch of different files of various sizes. However, when doing df without -h, I can see the "used" space going down, so that's something at least.
What exactly is happening here? How do I get the "avail" amount to go up without rebooting?
Edit: some people are saying that this might have to do with disk space that has been reserved, but this makes no sense. If disk has been reserved or not, if I delete files that are not currently open, the amount of disk available should go up, and that's not happening here.

In addition to the other answer: it may depends on the filesystem you are using. But I think you are below the 0% (so you are in the "reserve tank" of file system, just for root to be able to login)

What is the type of the filesystem? If from the ext family then read this. 5% of 99G is almost 5G, so deleting even "a few hundred megs" does not guarantee to bring the usage below the threshold.

I realize that ext reserves space, but how does that then translate into "removing files from disk doesn't free up any space" ? Even if space is reserved, removing a file should free up space. Also keep in mind all operations here are done as root.

I guess df shows what is available to regular users. By freeing some space, but not enough, you only increase free space for root; i.e. only root will be able to (re)use this space. Try to create files as root and as a regular user, and see. If you delete more and more then at some point you will "satisfy" the reserved space and the filesystem will start allowing regular users to use some of the freed space. Then df will show there is space available.

just in case, is /var on same filesystem as / ?(check bu cd /var/log ; df -h .  )

"I realize that ext reserves space, but …" – You still haven't told us if the filesystem is ext4, ext3 or what. Please [edit] and add the output of findmnt / and the output of findmnt -T /var/log/.

A few problems:

"a few dozen megabytes" of savings isn't going to show up in a human-readable (the -h) output if the numbers are in the gigabytes.
Files you delete that are still open by other processes will still be there; this may happen if you try to delete a logfile that a program still has open.
On most Linux filesystems, there's a "reserved" space that only root users (and most daemons) can fill. Even if you free up some space, regular users might not be able to write to that partition still. You can use something like tune2fs to see how much is reserved.


I tried this with a file of a few hundred megs, still same issue. I checked with lsof and there is no open file handle for this file, and I am running as the root user.

df-h, in your case, is showing data measured in Gb.  Deleting a few Mb files won't show up, here.
As you mention, without the -h you do see the used space go down.  So you are reclaiming space.  Just not enough.
You need to look for large files that may have been deleted but are still in use (lsof | grep deleted can help here) and restart the process holding open the large file.
You also need to look for large files that can be deleted; eg find / -xdev -size +500M -ls would find all files on the root partition over 500Mb in size.  On a 100Gb filesystem that may take some time, but it's a great way to find large wasteful files!
You can try a couple of short cuts; eg only search /tmp and /var  It's not uncommon to see a lot of stuff in /var, especially packages that were downloaded with apt and so can be removed, so du -hs /var/* | sort -h is sometimes useful.

I tried with some larger files, but same issue. And I tried both with and without the -h flag and disk available is still zero. None of the deleted files are in use, I checked with lsof. What is causing this?

You could truncate that file to save space:
# echo > /var/log/syslog

